# How to add a jasper preview into a JPanel

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a small report using jasper reports and I previewed it using the jasper viewer as below,

```
con = JDBCConnectionPool.getInstance().checkOut();
            String fileName = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/bio/ofm/mnu/views/reports/jasperReports/repAuditReport.jrxml").getFile();
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fileName);
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, con);
            JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(print);   
            viewer.setVisible(true);
```

But I need to show this report in a JPanel so, I tried as,

```
JasperViewer.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JRViewer jrv = new JRViewer(print);
            jrv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getSize()));
            JScrollPane reportScroll = new JScrollPane(jrv);
           panel1.add(reportScroll);
```

but the report is not showing as I expected, please explain what is the correct way to add a jasper preview in to a JPanel.

Comment: What layout manager is panel1 using? Are you adding the JScrollPane to the JPanel after the GUI has been displayed? If so, do you call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the JPanel after the addition?

Comment: @:hovercraft-full-of-eels, I hadn't set any layout manager before, but when I changed the layout manager to boxlayout manager report is showed,

Comment: It sounds like you're using NetBeans to generate your GUI code. If so, I strongly urge you not to do this until you understand Swing better, especially the layout managers. The Swing tutorials will tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JasperViewer extends JFrame, and you don't want to add a JFrame to a JPanel. You could perhaps add the JasperViewer's contentPane to the JPanel. The other issues I've discussed in a comment still remain unresolved:

What layout manager is panel1 using? Are you adding the JScrollPane to the JPanel after the GUI has been displayed? If so, do you call revalidate() and repaint() on the JPanel after the addition?

Comment: I called revalidate() and repaint() on jPanel, but it still having issue when I scroll. First time it works, but when I scroll in jasper report it gets back to first output.

Answer (score 2):

this my code and it works

```
       JRViewer jr=new JRViewer(print); 
       jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       jPanel1.repaint();
       jPanel1.add(jr);
       jPanel1.revalidate();
```